# Analog differential line driver and receiver circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, analog, noise

I want to do a "simple" task of transmitting 0-5v analog voltage from a potentiometer to a microcontroller 15ft away in a very noisy environment.
the available supply is 5V only (no negative voltage).

[image]

My idea is to use something like the digital line Driver/Receiver (AM26C31/AM26C32) but made for analog signals . **Is this possible ? Which circuit could achieve this?**

Does the signal have to be scaled down to 1/2 then use a 2.5V voltage reference, in order to avoid using a -5v negative supply?

**EDIT : according to answers by NEIL and OLIN , This is how i understand the circuit should be at the sender side, is this the schematic correct  ?**
[image: sch]

Comment: Yes, you can do it with opamps.

Comment: Your best bet would be to digitize it on one side and decode it on the other.

Comment: @dim , care to explain and post an answer with figure or reference ?

Comment: @EugeneSh. this is the last resort if it cannot be done in analog

Comment: I have my daughter baby in one arm, and typing on a tiny phone. Impossible yet but others will... But if uou come over and make her sleep, I can.

Comment: @ElectronS I would say it is a simplest and most robust solution... And I would risk to assume it would be cheapest.

Comment: I reformulated a bit to avoid shopping question confusion. There has been one close vote, question is good, no reason to risk having it closed.

Comment: Good luck with the girl

Comment: A digital line driver/reciever solution will only give you a digital 1/0 output - it won't pass the analog value of your sensor.

Comment: @dim , good luck with that , it seems harder than my task :)

Comment: What's the pot value? If you are just decoding the signal with a microcontroller ADC, you could perhaps use a current loop instead of a voltage.

Comment: @Lundin , sometimes we use 1k , or 4.7k or 10k max

Answer (score 4):

No potentiometer with moving parts has any significant high-frequency output.  So, just filter the 'received' voltage.  The more important issue may be the ground
connection, the '0' volt reference level.   Are there multiple ground connections in the system?  A ground loop will pick up any local magnetic field fluctuations.

Best connection scheme for a three-terminal potentiometer uses shielded 
three-wire cable, with the shield connecting to the metal shaft and case of 
the potentiometer, and grounded in ONE place.   The three wires connect
to the potentiometer terminals, of course.

The wiper contact of a potentiometer can be very reliable and low resistance with careful choice of materials.   The least expensive potentiometers (carbon film) are not as good as those with ceramic and conductive-plastic elements.

Answer (score 3):

You *could* use a differential transmitter, but really, only a differential receiver is needed. The two lines leaving your potentiometer would be the wiper, and the ground reference. It would be a good idea to connect a largish C across wiper and ground pot terminals, to equalise the drive impedance, at frequencies where you will pick up noise at least.

Run the two wires twisted, to minimise their inductive area.

At the receiver, use a differential or instrumentation amplifier to measure the voltage difference between the two lines, and refer it to the local ground.

If you insist on a differential transmitter as well, then a dual rail2rail  (as you only have 5v) opamp, with one inverting about mid-rail, one non-inverting, will do fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is a creature called differential amplifier. For example, THS4552. It will be a good driver, while instrumentation amplifier would be a good receiver. Just remember to keep good CMRR. Avoid resistors and capacitors unless they are symmetrical for both lines.

Answer (score 1):

I can propose you an external ADC with LVDS (low volatage **differential** signal) interface, e.g. **AMC1305L25** from TI. Thus you only need LVDS receivers at your uC to use the SPI interface for communication.

Answer (score 1):

### Differential voltage

Yes, it is possible to do what you ask, and it will help with noise immunity.  On the sending side, you invert the voltage about 2.5 V with unity gain.  That can be done very simply with a opamp.  You probably want to buffer the other signal too so that both lines have the same impedance.

On the receiving side, use a off the shelf differential amplifier to recover the single-ended signal.

### A better way

*However*, you obviously have power available at the sensor since you talk about it producing a 0-5 V signal as apposed to just a resistance.  If you're really worried about noise, convert to digital at the sensor and send the digital value.  That will have much more noise immunity.  It can also be isolated relatively easily.  If you've got that much noise, it's probably a good idea to not tie the ground together from points 15 feet apart.

Since the sensor is a potentiometer, the bandwidth is obviously low and the resolution requirement not very high.  A small micro with a 12 bit A/D won't be much more expensive or larger than the circuitry to send a differential analog signal.  This is a really easy thing to do.  Send the data out the micro using the UART, and have that create a current signal that drives the LED of a opto-isolator at the receiving end.

Again, the bandwidth is low, so a slow baud rate like 9600 is sufficient and should give very good noise immunity.  Sending two bytes per reading results in 480 samples/second.  This is very easy to do and isn't pushing any limits.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer , i liked both approaches that you presented, but i want to test the analog inorder to learn , i have modified the question with a schematic according to ur answer , can you tell me if it is correct ??. regards

Comment: @Ele: Your top circuit will have a gain of +2.  That might be OK if the receiver can deal with the voltage range.  However, the bottom circuit is not a proper inverting amplifier.  Note the positive feedback, for one thing.

Comment: sorry i goofed up , you are right , i will modify and reupload , just one question, in the buttom circuit , does the voltage divider connect to positive or negative input ?

Answer (score 1):

The two tools used to transmit analog signals in fairly noisy environments are current loops (4-20mA is the most popular in industry) and galvanic isolation. Combine those with shielding and most applications are covered.

If the situation is pathologically bad, you can consider an isolated supply, digitizing and using an optical fiber.

However, chances are in a moderately noisy situation you'd be just fine with a shielded cable to the pot and a low pass filter at the receiving end.

Comment: do you mean convert the Pot voltage into constant current source ? is this easly done ?

Comment: It's usually done with higher voltages than 5V, more like 24V.

Comment: i know this is an old answer, but could you please link to a question or other reference for building a current-loop around a sensor that produces a voltage output? it sounds simple, but i assume the devil's in the details, esp. if the signal might be below a single diode drop.

Comment: @RobStarling Thermocouple transmitters will work with a few mV full scale. The decent ones have isolation, so the power is derived from the current loop through a low power switching supply (isolated) which powers the analog signal conditioning, and the signal is passed over isolation back to the current loop driver through optical or other isolation in digital or analog form. Because of the custom magnetics and very low Iq switching supply this is not a snap-the-pieces together kind of design. Often there is a micro in there, sometimes HART is supported.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial drawing showed twin-lead (+ & - wires) with a shield.
How much noise do you measure, on the right hand side of the shielded cable?
And what SNR do you need?
Here is Signal Chain Explorer, with Sensor/pot producing 1 voltPP, into 5 meters of twinlead (diffpair wires), into 15Kohm, into 1uF+1nH ESL+1ohm ESR, into 12-bit ADC.
[image]

Here are the "analysis details", showing the resistor+realistic CAP+ESR+ESL reduces the wiring interference down adequately, with remaining errors being trash injection directly into ADC Vin.
[image]